# How can I edit the Inventory GUI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to edit the color of the GUI menus, specifically the inventory, to make it a different color. What file would this be under? I went into a resource pack I already have, and I found the generic_54.png file under the directory of:

```
C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\resourcepacks\[resourcepack]\assets\minecraft\textures\gui
```

It looks like the most likely file, but I just want to make sure. If so, I could just change the colors on it, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this directory:

```
C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\resourcepacks\
[resourcepack]\assets\minecraft\textures\gui\container\inventory.png
```

This image file also contains status effect icons, and their backgrounds.

*generic_54.png* refers to chests, for the most part.

Comment: That's great, thanks! Is there a way that I could find the heart, food, and armor icons? I can't find those.

Comment: The GUI icons for health, hunger and armor points are not full bars, but singular images located under:

`[resourcepack]\assets\minecraft\textures\gui\icons`

These are practically all in the \gui\ folder.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I couldn't find those! Thanks for your help!